# How do I setup SSL for a php single instance on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, csr

This is my first time setting up a dynamic website, so bare with me. My goal is to have SSL/https working on my php single instance aws Elastic beanstalk web app.

I already know that with a load balancer SSL is easy to set up and ACM certificates only work with load balancer.

I want single instance since it is cheaper. My project is small, don't expect a lot of traffic at most 1 user per day.

... back to problem, I did some research and came across this link, which is a "how to" from amazon:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html

The problem I'm running into is the part where I'm suppose to put my "certificate contents here".
From research what goes here is a SSL certificate from a third party. When I purchased my domain from namecheap , I also purchased PostivieSSL. Now where I'm confused is how to create this "cerificate contents". I found this link on namecheap:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9446/14/generating-csr-on-apache-opensslmodsslnginx-heroku/

**I know that I have to generate a CSR through SSH with commands ,where they will ask info about my site which is needed to make the request and get the certificate. It says I have to do this where I'm hosting my website. My question is how do I do this in elastic beanstalk? or is there another way to do this or am I understanding wrong. I'm a bit lost here**

I've spent 2 days researching but cant find how to do this. I've found some people linking GitHub repositories doing this in some other similar questions but they don't seem to help me understand how to do this.

Comment: If you're not worried about taking advantage of Elastic Beanstalk scaling and the like have you considered a single EC2 instance?  You won't be able to use the Amazon SSL certs but there are super easy ways to get that going.

Comment: I’ve faced this before. SSH to the instance (you might have to open your security group to allow this), and once logged in generate the CSR. Once you’ve generated the CSR, take a snapshot and use that snapshot for future instances (ie thats the snapshot your EB uses in future). Then add your certificate to your .ebextensions file and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was more or less in your shoes, but with the Java app instead of PHP. The way I see it, you have got three broad tasks to solve.

1. Generate proper certificate. You can either go for the one you already have from PositiveSSL or generate a free one for test purposes with Let's Encrypt and certbot (this might give you more control and understanding over what (sub)domain you're using it for). The end result is a set of certificate and key for the desired domain.
2. Make sure the certificate and key are on the Elastic Beanstalk instance in question and are being picked up by your web server. For this you need to properly package your app before deploying it, paying attention to the paths and the AWS docs for the single instance which you mentioned. Paste your certificate data in `.ebextensions/https-instance.config`, and it will be deployed as files under specified paths. Once you're done with the whole process later on, consider sourcing private certs and keys from your S3, never commit private data to version control.
3. Make sure the HTTPS traffic flows through. For this you'll need to make sure that your Elastic Beanstalk VPC security group has an inbound rule for port 443 (also covered in the AWS docs).